# is it possible to prove nested rule in prolog?

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to call a rule inside another rule my code is to fined the grandpa just like:

```
male(jack).
male(john).
male(mark).
parent(jack,john).
parent(john,mark).
father(X,Y):-male(X),parent(X,Y).
grandpa(X,Y):-father(X,father(F,Y)).
```

and the query in GNU Prolog is

```
grandpa(X,mark).
```

it just returns **no**
and when I tried to trace the call I noticed that it doesn't even call the nested rule.
So is there any way to do this in prolog?

Answer (score 1):

Rules aren't functions (which is why they aren't called functions): you don't *call* them, you *prove* them.  To do what you seem to be asking, you would write:

```
grandpa(X,Y) :- father(X,Z), father(Z,Y).
```

That is: X is Y's grandpa if there exists a Z such that X is Z's father and Z is Y's father.

Comment: Well I did this one but I wanted to know if I can "prove" a rule inside another instead of write it twice I meant by `father(X,father(F,Y)).` is that F is Y's father and then X is F's father if this is right X is Y's grandpa is this possible ?

Comment: @Mustafa Omar. Don't try to do something with a tool that is not intended to. You will take years to complete and maybe end with wrong concepts. Take the tool as it is, or don't.

Comment: @peter.cyc I'm currently learning prolog, my question wasn't about to "do something with a tool that is not intended to" but while writing the code I wanted to see if my idea is possible or not to write more efficient code.

Comment: @MustafaOmar You are under the mistaken impression that writing the relationship "twice" is "inefficient" (for user? or the machine?). But it's not. Every language expresses something in its own way (you wouldn't want to write LISP code in an SQL query either). Here, we want to basically express a graph, which is done `grandpa(X,Y) :- father(X,Z), father(Z,Y).`. That's the way it is. For "proving a rule inside another" you would first need to define a special "inside" relevant to "proving rules".